# Django REST Framework Import Error

Tags: django

I'm trying to install Django REST framework and I keep getting:

`No module named 'rest_framework'`

I've added:

`'rest_framework'` to my `INSTALLED_APPS = []`

I installed through `pip3` and it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Are you inside a virtualenv ?

Comment: Yeah, I am using a virtualenv and supervisor for Django.

Comment: I exited out of the virtualenv but everytime I install `djangorestframework`, I get this error: `Requirement already satisfied: djangorestframework in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages`

Comment: That looks like you installed it outside of your virtualenv. `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages` looks like the system Python path, rather than having a virtualenv for your Django app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not be the case. You might have installed globally or inside virtualenv.

Always installed your dependencies inside a virtualenv.

I think best way to get it working.

```
source <virtualenv>/bin/activate
pip install djangorestframework
```

Next whenever you work with your project re-enable back virtualenv.

Comment: This was the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Glad, If you did be kind enough to upvote the same as well :)